# My railfence cipher code works for small input sizes but when I take the input from a 250kb file It says seg fault

Tags: c++, c, char

My railfence cipher code works for small input sizes but when I take the input from a 250kb file It says seg fault. I tried changing the char*message from 10000 to 1000000 to take in larger inputs but it says segmentation fault. If i keep varying the number of 0s it only takes 0 as the input. How to I get it to work for large file sizes greater than or equal to 250KB?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* function to append a char to a char array */
void append(char* s, char c)
{
   int len = strlen(s);
   s[len] = c;
   s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    int num_rails;
    FILE *fp;
    char message[10000000];
    for (num_rails = 2; num_rails < 6; num_rails++)////minimum number of rails has to be 2.
    {
        //char* message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,1234567890";
        if ((fp = fopen("text_250kb.txt","r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! opening file");
            exit(1);
        }
        fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", message);
        printf("Data from file:\n%s", message);
        fclose(fp);

        int word_len = strlen(message);////takes in the input length of the string

        char* lines[num_rails];
        char* rails[num_rails];

        int len_rails[num_rails];
        memset(len_rails, 0, num_rails*sizeof(int));/*memset function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with a constant byte c. The memset function returns a pointer to the area s.*/
        int i,j,k,mod;
        int repeats;
        int period = (2*num_rails) - 2;//period is the number of characters consumed in one "zig-zag" across the rails and back again. Every rail is visited twice, except the first and last rails, so period = (2*num_rails) - 2

        printf("%d characters, %d rails:\n", word_len, num_rails);

        printf("\nplaintext: %s\n", message);

   /* encryption */

        for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
        {
            if ((lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(char))) == NULL)//if the number of characters in the line = Null, it will fail to allocate memory
            {
                printf("\nUnable to allocate memory.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        for (repeats = 0; repeats < ((word_len/period)+1); repeats++)
        {   
            if (repeats*period < word_len)
            append(lines[0], message[repeats*period]);

            for (j = 1; j < period/2; j++)
            {
                if ((j + (repeats*period)) < word_len)
                append(lines[j], message[j + (repeats*period)]);

                if ((((repeats+1)*period) - j) < word_len)
                append(lines[j], message[((repeats+1)*period) - j]); 
            }

            if (((period/2) + (repeats*period)) < word_len)
            append(lines[j], message[(period/2)+(repeats*period)]);
        }

        char encrypted[word_len];
        strcpy(encrypted,lines[0]);

        for (i = 1; i < num_rails; i++)
        strcat(encrypted, lines[i]);

        printf("\nciphertext: %s\n", encrypted);

   /* decryption */

        for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
        {
            if ((rails[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 40)) == NULL)//Multiply sizeof(int)by the number of integers you are planning to store in the array.
            {
                printf("\nUnable to allocate memory.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        mod = word_len % period;

        len_rails[0] = word_len / period;
        len_rails[num_rails-1] = len_rails[0];

        for (i = 1; i < num_rails - 1; i++)
            len_rails[i] = len_rails[0] * 2;

        for (i = 0; i < mod && i < num_rails; i++)
        {
            len_rails[i]++;
        }

        for (j = i-2; i < mod && j > -1; j--)
        {
            len_rails[j]++;
            i++;
        }

        printf("\nrail lengths:");
        for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
            printf(" %d", len_rails[i]);

        putchar('\n');
        k = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < num_rails; i++)
        {
             for (j = 0; j < len_rails[i]; j++)
            {
                 append(rails[i], encrypted[k++]);
            }
        }

        char deciphered[word_len];
        strcpy(deciphered, "");

        for (i = 0; i < ((word_len/period)+1); i++)
        {
            if (rails[0][i])
            append(deciphered, rails[0][i]);

            for (j = 1; j < num_rails-1; j++)
            {
                if (rails[j][i*2])
                append(deciphered, rails[j][i*2]);
            }
            if (rails[num_rails-1][i])
            append(deciphered, rails[num_rails-1][i]);

            for (j = num_rails-2; j > 0; j--)
            {
                if (rails[j][(i*2)+1])
                append(deciphered, rails[j][(i*2)+1]);
            }
        }

        printf("\ndeciphered: %s\n", deciphered);

        printf("==========================================\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try dynamically allocating `message`.

Comment: At least one problem is that you allocate memory for 1 symbol `lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(char))`, but then append something to it in the loop. You need to allocate more memory dynamically. However with `message` variable I don't see any mistakes.

Comment: Many systems impose a limit on the stack size, which is often 8 MiB on Unix/Linux systems, and usually smaller (like 1 MiB, I believe) on Windows.  When you increase the size of `message` to `10000000`, you are trying to allocate more than 8 MiB on the stack — which leads to the program crashing swiftly.  As @ScottHunter said, you could dynamically allocate the memory (`char *message = malloc(10000000);` and error check the allocation), or you could make it a variable defined outside of `main()` — `static char message[10000000];`.